# How is this possible? Visual Studio Dll's references

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, publish

I have two projects in two separate solutions - say p1 in s1 and p2 in s2. p1 is a web project and p2 is a web service project. Now, I have published p2 in a new directory, and add a reference from p1 to p2's published DLL (p2 compiled to a single dll file).
When I debug p1, and step into the functions from p2 namespace - instead of see it as an assembly page I see the actual page from p2 in s2! 
I wonder how it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

P.S
Due to my lack of English skills, I'd be grateful if anyone could edit the title to a more relevant one :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but I think VS recognizes the DLL by its GUID.